# HTML 5, CSS border outline inconsistency

Tags: css, html

I've looked around but not found a solution to this issue. Using the following CSS

```
border: double 1px #999;
outline: solid 4px #EAEAEA;
```

I was able to create a simple double border around a DIV quite easily. In HTML4. Then I switched the Document type to `<!DOCTYPE html>`, at which point the bottom outline was offset by about 5px. Curiously, only the bottom outline because the other 3 sides of the  are still flush with the border.

Am I missing something about border outlines in HTML5? I should stress that it looks perfect in HTML4.

Comment: In what browsers have you tested?

Comment: What browsers have you tried?

Comment: It works fine: http://jsfiddle.net/Er4UE/ Make a demo please.

Comment: Firefox 11. Looks fine in Safari. Not tried the others yet.

Comment: I'll try and reproduce this with jsfiddle but it's frustrating. Works fine as a HTML4 doc and fine in Safari, Firefox and IE. Latest versions of all browsers.

Comment: Here's the demo, look at it in Firefox and compare with something like Chrome. http://jsfiddle.net/Bzpj4/

Answer (score 1):

It may be quirks mode box-model issue (if you've used an incomplete Transitional `DOCTYPE` which doesn't enable "standards mode"). Without proper `DOCTYPE` you get emulation of IE5 bugs, including an "old" box-model.

The behavior you get *with* `<!DOCTYPE html>` is considered correct by the CSS spec.

Ideally you should reduce dimensions of the element by border width to compensate.

Alternatively (if you're using sizes in `%` for example), switch box-model to the one you expect (works in IE8+):

```
div {box-sizing: border-box;}
```

Note that it affects border only. The outline will be outside the box regardless, and it's not going to influence layout. You can reserve room for the outline using equivalent `margin`.

Comment: @Andy: add `margin:4px;`. outline is always outside the box, it'll never push away anything.